# how to get the length of object in an array in mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my database structure is something like this:
[model of messages in db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgUCH.png)
each documnet has "**receiverNumbers**" field with "**Object**" type:

```
receiverNumbers: {
  type: [{type: Object}],
  required: true
},
```

in this object, we have tow properties. "**phoneNumber**" and "**resultSend**" witch resultSend is an object that have few properties.

how can I get the length of receiverNumbers of all documents that the "**send**" property of "**resultSend**" object is **true**?

I know that I should use aggregate but I'm confused how.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your request output from them

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your input documents look like this :

```
{
  "_id": "id_1",
  "User": "user_1",
  "TotalNumber": 50,
  "SuccessNumber": 50,
  "__v": 0,
  "receiverNumbers": [
    {
      "phoneNumber": "01 23 45 67 89",
      "resultSend": {
        "senderNumber": "00 00 00 00 00",
        "messageText": "Hello World sent 1",
        "dateTime": "2023-01-18",
        "send": true
      }
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "01 23 45 67 89",
      "resultSend": {
        "senderNumber": "00 00 00 00 00",
        "messageText": "Hello World sent 2",
        "dateTime": "2023-01-18",
        "send": true
      }
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "01 23 45 67 89",
      "resultSend": {
        "senderNumber": "00 00 00 00 00",
        "messageText": "Hello World not sent 1",
        "dateTime": "2023-01-18",
        "send": false
      }
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "01 23 45 67 89",
      "resultSend": {
        "senderNumber": "00 00 00 00 00",
        "messageText": "Hello World sent 3",
        "dateTime": "2023-01-18",
        "send": true
      }
    },
    {
      "phoneNumber": "01 23 45 67 89",
      "resultSend": {
        "senderNumber": "00 00 00 00 00",
        "messageText": "Hello World not sent 2",
        "dateTime": "2023-01-18",
        "send": false
      }
    },
    
  ]
}
```

And that you want for each document the number of element in receiverNumbers where element.resultSend.send is true.

You could do something like this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "totalSend": {
        $sum: {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$receiverNumbers",
            "as": "val",
            "in": {
              $cond: [
                "$$val.resultSend.send",
                1,
                0,
                
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can check https://mongoplayground.net/p/crlKjIcmcWR for test.

Let me know if that answers your issue.

Comment: good but i have a problem. i have over 30K documents and i want to get the sum of all "**totalSend**" of each documents. it increase the order of time to retrieve it. any better idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "receiverNumbers.resultSend.send": true } },
  { $project: { length: { $size: "$receiverNumbers" } } },
]);
```

Comment: good. what if we have a query and want to "**and**" or something like this to the "**match**"? 
my function is like below:
`getMessagesCount(query) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
})
}`

Comment: @Amir_NOT not getting you!

Comment: i call this from a router: `sendMessages = await messageController.getMessagesCount(queryMessages);`  the query is `{"$and":[{"typeSend":"scheduled"},{"sendDate":{"$gt":"2023-01-20T20:30:00.000Z","$lt":"2023-01-21T20:29:59.000Z"}},{"status.type":"ended"}]}`. when i use `WhatsappMessage.aggregate([
        { $match: query },
        {
          $match: {
            "receiverNumbers.resultSend.send": true,
          },
        },
        { $project: { length: { $size: "$receiverNumbers" } } },
      ]);` got no answer.

Comment: the goal is find all document that is between two times and then aggregate throw matches document. at the end it should get back the **sum** of all length